# Bind Camel netty4 component to static port

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am newbie in Camel Netty4 component. I have a simple route:

```
    from("direct:sendMessageToStu")
            .to("netty4:udp://192.168.0.102:48000?sync=false&serverExceptionCaughtLogLevel=DEBUG");
```

It works properly, but I should to bind the outgoing socket's port to a static port, for example 32000. I can see the port is different in every times.
In netty, there is a simple way to fix it :

```
bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(32000));
```

But, how can I do that in Camel Netty4 component ?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible. Have you checked all the documentation? If no option exists you are welcome to log a JIRA ticket so we can add this in newer releases.

Comment: I guess I checked all the documentation. But there is a field in the options: option.XXX. Maybe this is an opportunity. Unfortunately I can't find any related documentation. Could you advise me one?